# Tool for measuring html-rendering time

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-rendering

I have speed problems with my Website (1.3MB).
The problem is particularly relevant in the Internet Explorer (7,8).
Now I'am searching a tool for measuring the rendering time (HTML, JavaScript, CSS).

Thanks for help !

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a profiling tool for IE. Knowing how popular IE is with web designers/developers, I am not surprised that there are not many tools. I used to use [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) from Yahoo in Mozilla browsers. When I had to test only in IE, (when my client insisted on it), I came across [MSFAST](http://msfast.myspace.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I would like to see the same

Answer (score 1):

One tool I found interesting is called *Speed Tracer*. It can be used to figure out, why your page loads that long. It differs from YSlow in the way that you see, what the Browser actually is doing. When it starts drawing the website on your screen, CSS evaluation, JavaScript execution and so on.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/

Here's a list of more useful developer tools provided by google:
https://developers.google.com/speed/tools

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google chrome, it has some excellent profiling tools.

See here for more info:

http://google-chrome-browser.com/google-chrome-developer-tools-profiling-and-optimizing

Comment: Thank's for your note, but this tool is measuring the time for the google chrome rendering-engine ?!

Answer (score -1):

Chrome, Safari (basically all WebKit-based browsers) do provide the Inspector which you can open by right-clicking on any place on a web site and choose "Inspect Element".